# How to split <table> into multiple <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, overflow

I am working with a large amount of data table (many lines many columns). The solution that I chose to use is putting my table into a `overflow:scoll div`. I would like to be able to see the 1st row even when scrolling down.

Is it possible to do it in `html` ? Otherwise, is there any trick like `js` trick?

Comment: Very possible but... what have you tried so far? This isn't a free programming request site where you ask if something is possible and others code it up for you.

Comment: @NewToJS I actually tried... No need to be that offensive with people that you don't know. I tried, didn't succeed, gave some web research, didnt succeed, then came here. Thanks for taking time to vote down & discharge some of your angriness on me :-)

Comment: Then maybe in future you should display what you have tried and also mention the research otherwise your question will appear to be nothing but a request for people to do it all for you. If you would like to disagree please spend some time reading this. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NewToJS I absolutely get what you mean and I absolutely agree with you message, but as long as this is a sharing & helping community, I guess that your last comment would have been more efficient as a 1st one than the actual 1st one... Explaining to people how they should have acted instead of attacking them is always more productive I guess...

Comment: You should read how to ask a question before asking, you can't put it on my if you can't be bothered to take the time to read how to submit a good question. If you don't have the time to spend on reading how to ask then expect blunt responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/s07w38me/

No JavaScript really required. You can simply `position: absolute` the contents of a div inside each `th`.

e.g.

**CSS**

```
th div {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- ...etc... -->
```

PS: This could be done a lot *better*, but this example above is a fork based on an existing JSfiddle I found.

Comment: This answers my need. Thanks Michael !

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you out. I would recommend reworking the example above to suit your specific needs. There are parts there that could do with improving.

Comment: That's what I did. Especially on the table displaying properties ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery.floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) (demos available) which is very cool, can work with DataTables too, and can even work inside an overflow: auto container.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try for more complex tables !

Answer (score 1):

The first row that you want to remain visible should be `position:fixed` and to set it to the top of that div `top:0`. Now your other columns would be overlapped by the `position:fixed` one, so make sure you give your scrollable div a `padding-top` equal to the height of the fixed column

Comment: This is a nice one too, even if the accepted answer suits me perfectly in my case ! Thanks